# How to center toast vertically and display at bottom of screen

Tags: android

This is a simple question. I Have this toast that is vertically centered, which appears in the middle of the screen.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx,"My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

How do I center the toast vertically **AND** display it at the bottom of my screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of vertical positioning. It means along the **y** axis – not **x**. To center it horizontally, and have it at the bottom of the screen – try the following:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Any idea how to add a margin because now it is touching the screen?

Comment: play with the **y** offset value – third parameter in 'setGravity'.

Answer (score 0):

The constants are a Gravity, x and y offset constants.

```
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```